# yandex static api требует CORS

Tags: yandex-maps-api, cors, yandex-static-maps-api

Пытаюсь загрузить на сайт статическую карту и получаю следующее сообщение:

```
Failed to load http://static-maps.yandex.ru/1.x/?size=390,270&l=map&pl=0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0&pt=0,0,round: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://www.mysite.ru' is therefore not allowed access.
```

В чем может быть проблема? В документации сказано, что можно бесплатно использовать без ключа.

Comment: Сам Static API работает без ключа и с его стороны не должно быть проблем с CORS. Вы можете убедиться в этом, собрав пример на jsfiddle или просто открыв изображение карты по ссылке в браузере.

Приведите, пожалуйста, код страницы, в котором делается обращение к Static API. Также, стоит обращаться к API по https.

Comment: @Reni 
Url: https://static-maps.yandex.ru/1.x/?size=390,270&l=map&pl=0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0&pt=0,0,round

Протестировать можно через сайты test-cors.org и resttesttest.com . Оба ругаются на CORS (можно открыть браузерную веб-консоль)

Comment: Static API требует отображения карты на странице и при размещении вызова API в теле страницы всё работает. Вот пример: https://jsfiddle.net/tpkboc5b/ 
Добавьте в вопрос код Вашей страницы, где Вы вызываете API и получаете ошибку с описанием решаемой задачи. Без этого не получится рассказать, что не так.

Comment: @Reni
https://jsfiddle.net/p5mxsa92/ 
Click on the text and see the browser console

Comment: какую задачу Вы хотите решить? static API в ответ возвращает изображение карты. Поясните, пожалуйста, что Вы хотите получить в результате, отправляя запрос таким образом?

Comment: @Reni - я таким образом скачиваю картинку и использую в своём сервисе.

Comment: Поясните, пожалуйста, как именно используете, тогда смогу Вам подсказать, как решить задачу. Пользовательское соглашение требует отображения карты на странице, пока похоже, что Вы его нарушаете, если я ошибаюсь - опишите свой сценарий и я попробую подсказать, как это сделать правильно, не сталкиваясь с ошибкой.

Comment: @Reni у меня Unity приложение, в котором нужно отобразить точку на карте по-координатам. Я делаю запрос по-url с координатами и получаю картинку, которую я загружаю в текстуру. В PC приложении все работает отлично. В WebGL (которое грузит через XMLHttpRequest) не хочет.

Comment: @GLeBaTi Static API не отдает заголовки CORS, так что вы не можете обработать данные, которые он отдает с помощью javascript'а (да и вообще получить к ним доступ). WebGL так же не работает с не-CORS-enabled картинками. Максимум, что вы можете сделать -  добавить динамически `<img>` с нужным `src` на страницу.

Comment: @flapenguin google static api работает у меня. Там так-же запросом получаю картинку. В яндекс апи получается нельзя так сделать? Даже если ключ будет?

Comment: Ключ в этом не поможет, но можно попробовать грузить картинку с сервера через свой прокси или curl'ом. А почему не подходит вариант с динамическим созданием img?

Comment: @Reni мне отобразить надо средствами webgl (не html)

Comment: я понимаю) Вы можете грузить изображение карты из API на свой сервер и уже через собственный прокси (с нужными CORS заголовками) отдавать его на web-страницу.

Comment: Да, видимо только так. Правда на сервер тогда нагрузка будет. Спасибо за помощь :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Специально для вас сегодня добавили cors-заголовки в ответе static api, можете пользоваться)

Comment: Спасибо, всё заработало!