# Как победить cors для cdek, pochta api во vue3 prodaction?

Tags: vue.js, api, yandex-maps-api, cors, vue3

Ошибка:`Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://otpravka-api.pochta.ru/1.0/tariff' from origin 'https://mysite.ru' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.` 
Запросы делаю с помощью [axios-mapper](https://github.com/RainManGO/axios-mapper):

```
const request: any = await httpsPochta().request<RootObject<any>>('/1.0/tariff', Method.POST, data, ContentType.json)
```

Развернул сервер для vue3, взял файлы из папки dist и залил на сервер с доменом; настроил nginx для работы ссылок: try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
Все работает отлично, к моему апи делает запросы без проблем
Если подключаю сторонние сервисы: cdek, pochta, yandex-map то вываливается ошибка CORS
Куда копать, ведь эти сервисы настроены для того, чтоб к ним делать запросы?

Comment: Ответ-же очевиден!! Ошибку то хотя-бы прочитал? `No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.`

Comment: Если ты имеешь ввиду вот так: `    headers: {
      'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
      'Access-Control-Allow-Methods':'GET,PUT,POST,DELETE,PATCH,OPTIONS',
      Authorization: hasToken ? `Bearer ${useStore().state.app.cdekToken}` : ''
    }`
То это не работает

Comment: Кто вам сказал что эти API должны работать из браузера?

Comment: Я имею ввиду что сервер должен при рендере отсылать `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: your.domain` ну или `*` если это публичный API.

Comment: Это получается, что мне из фронта нужно делать запрос на свой бэк, а из бэка на сервис сдека, почты и яндекса?

Comment: Вот этот сервис работает из браузера? https://confluence.cdek.ru/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=29923741

Answer (score 1):

CORS вы не победите, если сервер не ваш. Это настройка сервера. Похожий вопрос был - все зависит от того api  к которому вы обращаетесь, для яндекса есть сатики и не статик например. [yandex static api требует CORS](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/769477/yandex-static-api-%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B1%D1%83%D0%B5%D1%82-cors)

Копать вам надо в сторону документации к этим сервисам, вам правильно в комментах пишут - посмотрите в документации должны ли api  рабоать их браузера, или это api  для бекенда вашего приложения.